I want to verify bitbucket webhook secret. I wrote following code for lambda authorizer function for my api gateway )
import hashlib
import re
import os

# Secret from Bitbucket webhook settings
BITBUCKET_SECRET = os.environ.get('BITBUCKET_WEBHOOK_SECRET')  

def calculate_signature(bitbucket_signature, payload):
    """
    Signature calculator
    """
    signature_bytes = bytes(BITBUCKET_SECRET, 'utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(key=signature_bytes, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
    signature = digest.hexdigest()
    print(f"Calculated signature: {signature}")
    return signature

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Lambda execution starting...")
    incoming_signature = event['headers'].get('X-Hub-Signature')  # Bitbucket's signature header
    if incoming_signature is None:
        print("Signature header not found")
        return {
            'statusCode': 401,
            'body': 'Unauthorized'
        }
    incoming_signature = re.sub(r'^sha256=', '', incoming_signature)
    print(f"Incoming Signature: {incoming_signature}")
    calculated_signature = calculate_signature(incoming_signature, event['body'].encode('utf-8'))
    if incoming_signature != calculated_signature:
        print("Unauthorized attempt")
        return {
            'statusCode': 401,
            'body': 'Unauthorized'
        }
    else:
        print("Authorized access")
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Authorized'
        }

I am getting following error in lambda logs:
[ERROR] KeyError: 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 29, in lambda_handler
    calculated_signature = calculate_signature(incoming_signature, event['body'].encode('utf-8'))

I have checked lambda proxy integration in my API gateway
I tried tweaking API gateway settings and code here and there but I get stuck on this body error only
